# I am getting error while converting json to object

Tags: c#, json

i am trying to convert JSON to object following is my json

```
{"entity":"event","account_id":"acc_8yTsyb2WJOlcka","event":"payment.captured","contains":["payment"],"payload":{"payment":{"entity":{"id":"pay_AKR45WLH0g1ANu","entity":"payment","amount":100,"currency":"INR","status":"captured","order_id":"order_AKR41LsWIgOAB1","invoice_id":null,"international":false,"method":"netbanking","amount_refunded":0,"refund_status":null,"captured":true,"description":"Admission Fees","card_id":null,"bank":"SBIN","wallet":null,"vpa":null,"email":"xxxxx.xxxx@xxx.xxx","contact":"xxxxx","notes":{"address":"NA","merchant_order_id":"2516"},"fee":2,"tax":0,"error_code":null,"error_description":null,"created_at":1528367383}}},"created_at":1528367384}
```

and the code I am trying to convert to object is

```
 jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(documentContents);  
 RazorPayPayload desJsonString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RazorPayPayload>(jsonString);
```

and the classes where I want to deserialized

```
 public class RazorPayPayload
{
    public string entity { get; set; }
    public string account_id { get; set; }
    public string events { get; set; }
    public List<string> contains { get; set; }
    public payments payload { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
}
public class payments
{
    public Entities payment { get; set; }
}
public class notes
{
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string merchant_order_id { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
}
public class Entities
{
    public Entity entity { get; set; }
}
public class Entity
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string entity { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string order_id { get; set; }
    public string invoice_id { get; set; }
    public string international { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
    public string amount_refunded { get; set; }
    public string refund_status { get; set; }
    public string captured { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string card_id { get; set; }
    public string bank { get; set; }
    public string wallet { get; set; }
    public string vpa { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string contact { get; set; }
    public notes notes { get; set; }
    public string fee { get; set; }
    public string tax { get; set; }
    public string error_code { get; set; }
    public string error_description { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the error "Error converting value to type 'FeePayr_Razor_Webhook.RazorPayPayload'"

Comment: Have you tried to narrow the problem down at all? Currently you have a lot of JSON and a lot of properties. The first thing I normally do at this stage is reduce the size of the problem.

Comment: Check if your json and model are compatible. You can generate the c# classes using any online tool like http://json2csharp.com/.

Comment: The code you've given works fine with the JSON you've given. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure that `jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(documentContents);` is what you want? What is `documentContents`? If that's the JSON string you've shown, then that's the problem - you should just be calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RazorPayPayload>(documentContents);`. This is where a [mcve] would make things a lot clearer.

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RazorPayPayload>(documentContents);

Comment: Thanks @DaisyShipton that works

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing:

```
 {"entity":"event","account_id":"acc_8yTsyb2WJOlcka","event":
```

to

```
{"entity":"event","account_id":"acc_8yTsyb2WJOlcka","events":
```

That would better match your class definition. Or rename your class field to *event*.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful visual studio function for converting a json object to c# classes.

Copy the JSON into the clipboard. (helps if the JSON object properties holds data, to determine the data type)

Go to visual studio and place cursor where you'd like to paste in the c# classes.

click edit => paste special => paste json as classes